# Pycharm Theme - no python colored syntax

Tags: python, pycharm, themes

I am using Pycharm Pro 2020.1.2.
When I load the theme Monokai Pro (similar behavior for other theme) I don't have the expected Python colored code.
I expect to have the one displayed in Ctlr+Alt+S->Editor->Color Scheme->Python

[image]

But when I open a python file, the colored code is the following:
[image]

How can I enforce the colored code seen in Color Scheme->Python to the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your changes not getting effected. I tried using duplicate schema and it works.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have restored the original Pycharm setup and then it was working like a charm. I guess there was a bug/undesired flag that prevent some of my python code to reflect the right color code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate schema and make changes as per your convenience.

[image]

Comment: The thing is I am happy with Monokai Pro, I just want what I see in Ctlr+Alt+S->Editor->Color Scheme->Python to really be applied to my code. I have tried to duplicate the theme, but (as expected) no change in terms of want I see in the Editor. It is like Pycahrm doe snot reco that my file is a python file (even if I have checked that *.py are asociated with the Python theme Ctrl+Alt+S->Editor->File Types->Python)